# list-style-image not working with gmail in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gmail, html-email

I am creating email-templates and run into problem with bullet lists. I can´t get images in list to work with Chrome, I would like to stick to list-style-image rather than using background-image on li-tag... Is there a solution for this?

```
ul {
list-style-image: url('../images/Bullet_list_check_sign.png') !important;
display: inline-block !important;
padding-left: 20px !important;
}
ul li {
line-height: 45px !important;
padding-left: 15px !important;
display: list-item !important;
}

<div>
<ul>
<li>Nulla efficitur felis</li>
<li>Nulla efficitur felis</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 5):

Technically `<ul>`, `<ol>`, and `<li>` are supported in email as semantic tags, but we can't control them reliably with CSS as we can on the web. So many times we're sorta stuck with however an email client decides to display them. Not ideal.

If you'd like a consistently displayed list, it's best to create the list as a `<table>`:

```
<!-- Bullet List -->
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="0"> 
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">&#8226;</td>
    <td>List Item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">&#8226;</td>
    <td>List Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">&#8226;</td>
    <td>List Item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think a width and text alignment will make the bullet look better. `<td width="20" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:center;">&#8226;</td>`

Answer (score 2):

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Gmail does not support the `list-style-type` style. Another solution could be to inline the images and 'fake' the bullet positioning.